# how to add multiple cvs file from folder to database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv, import

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim directory = "D:\Test"
Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo
Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.csv", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

I get the directory info of where csv files in. I want to get all csv files to my vb database. My database sample is zipcode; state; city. I try many of ways to get csv files but I can only get one csv file to database. Every day csv files add the folder and I have to 
add them automaticly to the database. Can you give me an idea

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do something for one item then you know how to do it for any number of items.  You simply put the code for one item in a loop.  In your code, `files` is an array of `FileInfo` objects.  Write a method that takes a `FileInfo` object and imports the data from that file into your database.  Now just use a `For Each` loop to enumerate your array and call your method for each element, e.g.

```
For Each file In files
    ImportData(file)
Next
```